# Program crashing due to low RAM

Tags: memory, freeze, handle

Hi We have a machine that is controlled by a 
Windows 7 proffesional 32 bit machine.
The machine is controlled by a software application that requires a machine with 4 GB ram. 
Sometimes the application freezes. I whent in to the task manager and noted the ram usage for when it was running fine and when it was running slow.

```
 Physical Memory (T,C,A,F)3253,1230,1245,45 in the frozen state,
 Physical Memory (T,C,A,F)3253,1573,1554,44 in the good  state.
```

So I dont think it is the physical memory

```
 Kernel memory (MB) Paged/NonePaged 321,366 frozen
 Kernel memory (MB) Paged/NonePaged 239,227  good
```

That looks like something I should investigate.

And then there is the system

```
 Handles/Threads/Processes/Uptime/Commit(MB) 854777,1283,80,6:21:04:45,2182/6504(Frozen)
 Handles/Threads/Processes/Uptime/Commit(MB) 38806,1219,79,0:00:21:40,1880/6504(running)
```

I am guessing from the system that uptime could have something to do with it does that seem likely to you guys?

Comment: Why run the 32 bit version of Win 7?

Answer (score 3):

You are running software which requires 4 GB of memory. However, you are running a 32-bit version of Windows 7 and so do not allow the software access to 4 GB of memory.

Run it on a computer which meets the minimum requirements. If your computer has sufficient memory, the 64-bit version of Windows 7 may be sufficient.

This, of course, assumes you are correct that memory is the issue. It could simply be that the software has a bug which causes it to freeze, and you need to take it up with the software developers. It's not possible to tell, given the information you have provided.

Comment: One could enable [PAE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366796(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows 7 but that only solves the problem for a single application and is not really a solution.  The application is still going to run out of memory, since it still will be unable to allocate enough memory, which based on its requirements is likely more then 3GB.

Comment: Hi @chrisinedmonton, my program is specked to run on a 32bit is with 4 GB ram. It specifically says writes in the manual that the 64bit is not supported.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your 32-bit version of Windows has access to all 4 GB of RAM? That would be almost unheard of. You also haven't explained why you think the problem is memory.

Comment: It specifies that the program runs on a 32Bit machine that has 4GB ram, it does not say that it uses all that ram. Also I I think that it is a memory problem or incorrect use of memory by the application. The reason for this is based on the fact of the differences in the memory usage state based on whether the machine is frozen or not.